# Weird integer conversion with structs and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I'm trying to create a stack in C and when I 'push' to it, based on int*s, after the second push I get a weird number transformation, from -3 to an odd large number. Here is my code. I appreciate anyone's insight.

```
typedef struct
{
  int current_stack_size;
  int *stack; // base of stack
  int *leading; // extreme top, to place new int
  int *top_of_stack_ptr; // base of top, to retrieve
} MinStack;

MinStack *minStackCreate()
{
  MinStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(MinStack));
  stack->current_stack_size = 0;
  stack->stack = malloc(sizeof(int));
  stack->top_of_stack_ptr = stack->stack;
  stack->leading = stack->stack;
  return stack;
}

void minStackPush(MinStack *obj, int x)
{
  if (obj->current_stack_size == 0)
  {
    *(obj->stack) = x;
    obj->current_stack_size++;
    obj->leading += sizeof(int);
    return;
  }
  else if(obj->current_stack_size > 0){
    obj->current_stack_size++;
    obj->stack = realloc(obj->stack, sizeof(int) * (obj->current_stack_size));
    *(obj->leading) = x;
    obj->leading += sizeof(int);
    obj->top_of_stack_ptr += sizeof(int);
    if (x == -3){  // for debug purposes
      printf("X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = %d\n", obj->top_of_stack_ptr);
    }
  }
void print_state(MinStack *stack, char *op)
{
  printf("Current Stack Size: %d\n", stack->current_stack_size);
  printf("Stack Size:%d Last Operation: %s\n", stack->current_stack_size, op);
  for (int i = 0; i < stack->current_stack_size; i++)
  {
    int value = **((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);
    printf("%d:%d\n", i, value);
  }
  return;
}


int main(void)
    {
      MinStack *stack = minStackCreate();
      minStackPush(stack, -2);
      print_state(stack, "pushed -2");
      minStackPush(stack, 0);
      print_state(stack, "pushed 0");
      minStackPush(stack, -3);
      print_state(stack, "pushed -3");
      minStackPush(stack, -3);
      print_state(stack, "pushed -3");
      minStackPush(stack, -3);
      print_state(stack, "pushed -3");
    ...
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Current Stack Size: 1
Stack Size:1 Last Operation: pushed -2
0:-2
Current Stack Size: 2
Stack Size:2 Last Operation: pushed 0
0:-2
1:0
X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = -605719824  // This is unexpected
Current Stack Size: 3
Stack Size:3 Last Operation: pushed -3
0:-2
1:0
2:170932785 // this is unexpected
X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = -500317440
Current Stack Size: 4
Stack Size:4 Last Operation: pushed -3       
0:-2
1:0
2:170932785
3:1884233844
```

and so on

It only happens after the third push, whether I give it -3 or 10.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with realloc, but I don't know exactly what.

I thought I was giving the buffer just enough space to grow. True I was increasing the leading pointer ahead of the buffer by one int's worth, but I wasn't writing to it until I grew it just enough. Maybe I was off in my calculations, so I gave it some extra padding in both conditions (current_stack_size == 0 or 1). This didn't fix it.

I decided to brute force initially malloc the stack->stack to `sizeof(int) * 50` and it worked. Strangely the numbers still came up wrong in my debug output (where I write "This is unexpected") but in the stack output itself it was good. I still wanted to know what's going on and have the ability to dynamically realloc it to size.

Then I thought I figured it out: My "leading" and "top_of_stack_ptr"s probalby lost their reference to the memory buffer of stack->stack, so to speak when using realloc. I believe they were "orphaned" by realloc, dissociated from the their parent. I was sure this was what happened and that the outputI was getting was just random noise from memory. The fix would be easy. Instead of `stack->leading += sizeof(int)`, after `obj->stack = realloc(obj->stack, sizeof(int) * (obj->current_stack_size));`, I did `obj->leading = obj->stack + sizeof(int) * obj->current_stack_size;` and `obj->top_of_stack_ptr = obj->leading - sizeof(int)`. It didn't solve it at all like I was convinced it would.

Then, forgetting that mallocing originally to `sizeof(int)* 50` fixed my problem, I started to think I needed int**s (double pointers) because I need pointer to an int array. This made so much sense to me but gave me a seg fault. I thought the issue was just the need to double dereference in places and malloc differently, but here's what I changed to my struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int current_stack_size;
  int **stack;            // base of stack
  int **leading;          // extreme top, to place new int
  int **top_of_stack_ptr; // base of top, to retrieve
} MinStack;
```

My segfault came right here:

```
void minStackPush(MinStack *obj, int x)
{
  if (obj->current_stack_size == 0)
  {
    *(obj->stack) = x; // THIS creates a seg fault
    printf("Pushing\n");
```

Now I think I was wrong about the need for double pointers. A pointer to an int is already an array when you malloc it. A double pointer could give you a 2d array. BTW I was eager to start learning double-pointers. This is why C can be challenging but also why I love it. Even though I haven't solved the issue yet, a couple different times I felt like things seemed really clear to me.

So what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is certainly worthy of an upvote due to the time and effort spent in proper formatting and in providing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (including the headers would be a nice touch next time `:)`

Answer (score 1):

After `minStackCreate()`, in `minStackPush()` when `obj->leading += sizeof(int);` is encountered, `obj->leading` points immediately past the block of memory allocated in `minStackCreate()` with `MinStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(MinStack));` When `*(obj->leading) = x;` attempts to assign an integer to the address, *Undefined Behavior* is invoked.

**Memory Use/Error Check**

A simple memory use/error check details the problem.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/minstack
==22103== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22103== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22103== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22103== Command: ./bin/minstack
==22103==
Current Stack Size: 1
Stack Size:1 Last Operation: pushed -2
0:-2
==22103== Invalid write of size 4
==22103==    at 0x4006A6: minStackPush (minstack.c:36)
==22103==    by 0x4007C9: main (minstack.c:62)
==22103==  Address 0x51f40b0 is 12 bytes after a block of size 4 free'd
==22103==    at 0x4C3023F: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22103==    by 0x40068F: minStackPush (minstack.c:35)
==22103==    by 0x4007C9: main (minstack.c:62)
==22103==  Block was alloc'd at
==22103==    at 0x4C2E01F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22103==    by 0x4005D0: minStackCreate (minstack.c:18)
==22103==    by 0x400792: main (minstack.c:59)
==22103==
Current Stack Size: 2
Stack Size:2 Last Operation: pushed 0
0:-2
==22103== Invalid read of size 4
==22103==    at 0x400753: print_state (minstack.c:50)
==22103==    by 0x4007DA: main (minstack.c:63)
==22103==  Address 0x51f4540 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==22103==    at 0x4C3023F: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22103==    by 0x40068F: minStackPush (minstack.c:35)
==22103==    by 0x4007C9: main (minstack.c:62)
==22103==
1:0
==22103== Invalid write of size 4
==22103==    at 0x4006A6: minStackPush (minstack.c:36)
==22103==    by 0x4007EB: main (minstack.c:64)
==22103==  Address 0x51f40c0 is 16 bytes after a block of size 16 in arena "client"
==22103==
==22103== Invalid read of size 4
==22103==    at 0x4006DE: minStackPush (minstack.c:40)
==22103==    by 0x4007EB: main (minstack.c:64)
==22103==  Address 0x51f40c0 is 16 bytes after a block of size 16 in arena "client"
==22103==
X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = -3
Current Stack Size: 3
Stack Size:3 Last Operation: pushed -3
0:-2
==22103== Invalid read of size 4
==22103==    at 0x400753: print_state (minstack.c:50)
==22103==    by 0x4007FC: main (minstack.c:65)
==22103==  Address 0x51f4590 is 4 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==22103==    at 0x4C3023F: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22103==    by 0x40068F: minStackPush (minstack.c:35)
==22103==    by 0x4007EB: main (minstack.c:64)
==22103==
1:0
2:0
==22103== Invalid write of size 4
==22103==    at 0x4006A6: minStackPush (minstack.c:36)
==22103==    by 0x40080D: main (minstack.c:66)
==22103==  Address 0x51f40d0 is 32 bytes before a block of size 1,024 in arena "client"
==22103==
==22103==
==22103== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==22103==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1051F40C4
==22103==    at 0x4006DE: minStackPush (minstack.c:40)
==22103==    by 0x40080D: main (minstack.c:66)
==22103==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22103==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22103==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22103==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22103==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==22103==
==22103== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22103==     in use at exit: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==22103==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 4 frees, 1,096 bytes allocated
==22103==
==22103== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22103==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22103==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22103==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22103==    still reachable: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==22103==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22103== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22103==
==22103== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22103== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You have two additional problems invoking undefined behavior.

```
    if (x == -3){  // for debug purposes
        printf("X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = %d\n", obj->top_of_stack_ptr);
    }
```

You were attempting to print an integer pointer with `%d`. If you want to print the pointer address use `%p` and cast the pointer to void, e.g. use:

```
        printf("X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = %p\n", (void*)obj->top_of_stack_ptr);
```

If you did want to output the integer value, you need:

```
        printf("X is -3, so clearly obj->top_ptr = %d\n", *obj->top_of_stack_ptr);
```

You have a similar problem with:

```
    int value = **((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);
```

Which it is unclear how you compiled since that results in:

```
    minstack.c:49:17: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
         int value = **((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);
```

You have one level of indirection too many. To fix you would need:

```
    int value = *((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);
```

You will need to go address each of these issues.

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

If you have trouble further resolving these issues, drop a comment below and I'm happy to help further.

---

**Fixing Your Indexing**

After cleaning up the errors indicated above, your next biggest problem is:

```
    int value = *((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);
```

Your value is at:

```
    int value = stack->stack[i];
```

By including `(address) + (4 * i)` you are indexing well beyond your allocated storage attempting to print the value.

**Allocation Logic**

You are over-complicating your allocation logic. In `MinStack *minStackCreate()`, you are creating a `MinStack` object, so just allocate for that. You do not need to allocate for `stack->stack` yet, you have no value for it, so just initialize `stack->stack = NULL;`, e.g.

```
MinStack *minStackCreate()
{
  MinStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(MinStack));
  stack->current_stack_size = 0;
  stack->stack = NULL;
  return stack;
}
```

Now in `int *minStackPush(MinStack *obj, int x)`, you do not need a `if ... then ...` conditional to handle adding the 1st value or subsequent values. `stack->stack` is initialized `NULL`, so just call `realloc()` add space for one additional integer and update the pointers appropriately, e.g.

```
int *minStackPush(MinStack *obj, int x)
{
  /* always realloc using temporary pointer to prevent memory leak on failure */
  void *tmp = realloc (obj->stack, (obj->current_stack_size + 1) * sizeof *obj->stack);
  if (!tmp) {
    perror ("realloc-obj->stack");
    return NULL;
  }
  obj->stack = tmp;
  obj->leading = obj->stack + obj->current_stack_size;
  obj->top_of_stack_ptr = obj->leading;
  *obj->leading = x;
  
  obj->current_stack_size++;
  
  return obj->stack;
}
```

(**note:** I have changed the return type to `int*`. You allocate memory within the function so you need a way to determine success/failure. It's not a matter of "if" a reallocation will fail, it is a matter of "when" a reallocation fails. It's not so much what your return, (e.g. `int`, or `int*`, etc...). It is the fact that you can determine whether the allocation succeeded or failed that is important. Choose a convenient and reasonable return type that works. You can incorporate the return check where you call the function)

Your `printf()` was causing no end of problems. As addressed above, you were attempting to access memory beyond your allocation. You have an object `stack` and that object contains a pointer to an allocated block of integer values (e.g. `stack->block` -- block used to avoid confusion with which `stack` in `stack->stack`). Just index `block` as an array, e.g. `stack->block[i]`. When you need to index an integer within the allocated block, simply index as you would with an array, e.g.

```
void print_state(MinStack *stack, char *op)
{
  printf ("Stack Size:%d Last Operation: %s\n",
          stack->current_stack_size, op);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < stack->current_stack_size; i++)
    printf("%d:%d\n", i, stack->stack[i]);
}
```

Putting the refined logic together, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
  int current_stack_size;
  int *stack; // base of stack
  int *leading; // extreme top, to place new int
  int *top_of_stack_ptr; // base of top, to retrieve
} MinStack;

MinStack *minStackCreate()
{
  MinStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(MinStack));
  stack->current_stack_size = 0;
  stack->stack = NULL;
  return stack;
}

int *minStackPush(MinStack *obj, int x)
{
  /* always realloc using temporary pointer to prevent memory leak on failure */
  void *tmp = realloc (obj->stack, (obj->current_stack_size + 1) * sizeof *obj->stack);
  if (!tmp) {
    perror ("realloc-obj->stack");
    return NULL;
  }
  obj->stack = tmp;
  obj->leading = obj->stack + obj->current_stack_size;
  obj->top_of_stack_ptr = obj->leading;
  *obj->leading = x;
  
  obj->current_stack_size++;
  
  return obj->stack;
}

void print_state(MinStack *stack, char *op)
{
  printf ("Stack Size:%d Last Operation: %s\n",
          stack->current_stack_size, op);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < stack->current_stack_size; i++)
    printf("%d:%d\n", i, stack->stack[i]);
}


int main(void)
{
    MinStack *stack = minStackCreate();
    for (int i = -5; i < 6; i++) {
        char buf[32];
        minStackPush (stack, i);
        sprintf (buf, "pushed: %d", i);
        print_state (stack, buf);
    }
    
    free (stack->stack);
    free (stack);
}
```

(**note:** your `top_of_stack_ptr` and `leading` perform the same function. You don't need a separate pointer to point where the next `int` should be added, since that is nothing but a simple offset based on `current_stack_size`. So remove one or the other. Personally, I'd ditch `leading` as `top_of_stack_ptr` is what you are actually wanting)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/minstack_fixed
Stack Size:1 Last Operation: pushed: -5
0:-5
Stack Size:2 Last Operation: pushed: -4
0:-5
1:-4
Stack Size:3 Last Operation: pushed: -3
0:-5
1:-4
2:-3
Stack Size:4 Last Operation: pushed: -2
<...snip...>
Stack Size:11 Last Operation: pushed: 5
0:-5
1:-4
2:-3
3:-2
4:-1
5:0
6:1
7:2
8:3
9:4
10:5
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/minstack_fixed
==29254== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29254== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29254== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29254== Command: ./bin/minstack_fixed
==29254==
Stack Size:1 Last Operation: pushed: -5
0:-5
Stack Size:2 Last Operation: pushed: -4
0:-5
1:-4
Stack Size:3 Last Operation: pushed: -3
0:-5
1:-4
2:-3
<...snip...>
Stack Size:11 Last Operation: pushed: 5
0:-5
1:-4
2:-3
3:-2
4:-1
5:0
6:1
7:2
8:3
9:4
10:5
==29254==
==29254== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29254==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29254==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 1,320 bytes allocated
==29254==
==29254== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29254==
==29254== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29254== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks. The " int value = *((stack->stack) + sizeof(int) * i);" was just a typo. Outputting to integer value *obj->top_of_stack_ptr) was an oversight that's fixed and consoles correctly. The buckets starting at #2 were still wrong though. I went through all the suggestions over and over and still got weird output. The thing that fixes it is to have a min realloc value (inside elseif) of current_stack_size + 5) * sizeof(int). I don't know why but anything less than +5 puts wrong numbers in stack.

Comment: @gcr The key is this, when you first set `stack->leading = stack->stack;` in `create()`, it points to the original address for `stack->stack`. When you `realloc()` nothing changes that address. So `stack->leading` still points to the original `stack->stack` which is an invalid address after `realloc()`. The values of anything less, etc.. is just the side effect of undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that pointer gets orphaned. I fixed it earlier as follows (after realloc): `obj->leading = obj->stack + (sizeof(int) * obj->current_stack_size);`, I just didn't have space to show. Did same with top_of_stack_ptr. It still produced unexpected output.

Comment: Also recall that *pointer type* controls *pointer arithmetic*. So when you provide `stack->stack + 1`, the new address will be 4-bytes after `stack->stack` point to the next *integer* value. (which is also why you cannot do pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers -- the size information is incomplete)

Answer (score 0):

Your are jumping too much in memory.

```c
      obj->leading++; // += sizeof(int);
      obj->top_of_stack_ptr++; // += sizeof(int);
```

and

```c
      int value = *((stack->stack) + /* sizeof(int) * */ i);
```

should fix your pointer arithemtic.

Other problems are already pointed out from other answers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it didn't work for me without sizeof(int). I don't know why. Consistency? Would be nice to not have to do that.  Good use case for macro anyway.